# Fail to load custom mongoose schema in another js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I've this project folder structure:

[image: Project folder structure -> see the image]

And I'm trying to import my user schema in my user ctrl but when i start nodemon users.ctrl.js gives me this error:

```
const {Users} = require('users.schema');

      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

This is the user schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
// {
//   email: 'andrew@example.com',
//   password: 'adpsofijasdfmpoijwerew',
//   tokens: [{
//     access: 'auth',
//     token: 'poijasdpfoimasdpfjiweproijwer'
//   }]
// }
var Users = mongoose.model('Users', {
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 1,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      validator: validator.isEmail,
      message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email'
    }
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6
  },
  tokens: [{
    access: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    token: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }]
});
module.exports = {Users}
And this is the user ctrl:

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Users} = require('users.schema');

getAll = (req, res) => {
  // let id = req.params.userId;
  console.log('GET all cards');
  Users
    .find()
    .select('users')
    .exec((err, doc) => {
      console.log('Risultato: ', doc);
    });
};

module.exports = {
  getAll
};
```

And this is the user ctrl:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Users} = require('users.schema');

getAll = (req, res) => {
  // let id = req.params.userId;
  console.log('GET all cards');
  Users
    .find()
    .select('users')
    .exec((err, doc) => {
      console.log('Risultato: ', doc);
    });
};

module.exports = {
  getAll
};
```

Where am I wrong? Is there something that escapes me?

Comment: Use relative paths. Node is trying to resolve the given package name from the `node_modules`. Simply replace the require statement with `require('./users.schema')`.

Answer (score 0):

By default node corresponds to `/node_modules` where the node packages are stored. Hence use relative path names to access the file `require(./filename)`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

On this current pc that i'm using i had node version number 5.0.7 . To use the new ecma6 features i need to install v 8.0.... 
After installing the version I solved the problemAfter installing the version I solved the problem